# Python: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

Tags: python, flask, instagram-api

I have backend code which is supposed to download instagram profile picture and send it to frontend and after that it should delete the folder where that picture is stored. It works when it comes to sending the image to frontend, but it won't delete folder after its done. The folder structure when picture is downloaded:

username(folder to be deleted)

1. profile-picture.jpg
2. username.date.json.xz
3. id

Error says it has problem with deleting the file because profile-picture.jpg is used by another process

```
import os
import shutil
from flask import Flask, request, send_file
import instaloader

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get-profile-picture')
def get_profile_picture():
    try:
        username = request.args.get('username')
        mod = instaloader.Instaloader()
        mod.download_profile(username, profile_pic_only=True)
        print("before send")
        return send_file(f'{username}/' + os.listdir(f'{username}')[0])
    except instaloader.exceptions.ProfileNotExistsException:
        return "Profile doesn't exist"
    finally:
        delete_folder(username)
        

def delete_folder(folder_name):
    if os.path.isdir(folder_name):
        shutil.rmtree(folder_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you close the file once you have saved it to memory in the image download function? The same for when you open it to send it to the front end. You can either use with or close the file manually once you finish the processing you need to do.